# Validating a form fails but gives no errors

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony

I am trying to create a form without a class in Symfony3. Unfortunately though the validation fails but gives me no message at all - just an emtpy string.

```
public function postCollectionAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    $options = ["csrf_protection" => false];

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder([], $options)
        ->add('elements', CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type'   => MyClassType::class, //this should be form type
                'allow_add' => true, // this needs to be true
            ]
        )
        ->getForm();

        $form->submit($data); // This was the main problem - form did not get submitted

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        die("ok");
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump((string)$form->getErrors(true, false));
        die("not ok");
    }
}
```

The class I am trying to validate looks like this

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table
 */
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;
}
```

And this is what I am sending it

```
{
    "elements": [{
        "name": "My element name"
    }]
}
```

I think I am missing the obvious. Can someone please help me to make this work?

**UPDATE** Edited the code with Alvin Bunk suggestions

Comment: Are you using Symfony3 or Symfony2?

Comment: @AlvinBunk It is symfony 3 I am using. Did not know form component has changed - I will remove the confusing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks odd the way you create that form, but I understand it (and it might? work...) , but how about trying this instead:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, $options)
    ->add('elements', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => MyClass::class,
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

Try it and see what happens.
Did you also try the 'app_dev.php' URL to see if it shows more information?

Edit #2...

I think your JSON is wrong.
Should be like this:

```
{
    "elements": {
        "name": "My element name"
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work because the validation fails. I tried null instead and it did not work either... The code is mostly from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class

Comment: Also, check your logs in var/logs, either dev.log or prod.log.

Comment: But I am getting the output, this is not the exception being thrown. The actual output is  string(0) ""  not ok in app_dev.php

Comment: The log says only that the route has matched and Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token

Comment: I notice you have no Submit button. Also you show no code how you pass in "{
    "elements": [{
        "name": "My element name"
    }]
}".

Comment: Right, for some reason having         $form->handleRequest($request); was not enough and I have to explicitly         $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);   $form->submit($data); The error now is "This form should not contain extra fields', but at least it shows it. I POST the data to the endpoint using a REST client

Comment: I thinks it's your json. Can you verify and see if I'm right. I believe that's what the error message is telling you too, that you are sending too many fields.

Comment: it was missing                     'allow_add' => true, in the options array, so it is now better, I updated the code accordingly, but now it does not allow to add more that one MyClass without failing but having empty $form->getData()["elements"]...

Comment: Edited my code, and the problem I am facing now seems to be beyond the original question. Thanks a lot!